# How can I generate toString() method from fields?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

I have a Java class which contains fields like this:

```java
private int port;
private String portName;
private ArrayList portList;
private int id;
```

I need a command or script so I can directly paste the above block in terminal and give it as input to that command or script and give me following output:

```java
public String toString() {
    return "{ " + "port=" + port + ",portName=" + portName + ",portList=" + portList + ",id=" + id + "}";
}
```

Comment: So you want to implement this in Bash? Have you already tried it yourself? Should be pretty simple.

Comment: FWIW, you can implement this once for all classes in Java with reflection, so you don't have to rely on code generation tools. If you post a suitable question on [SO] and send me a link, I'll write an answer.

Comment: You could also consider using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) to generate this method (and others). Once your project is set up with Lombok, all you would do is add an annotation to your class (`@ToString` in this case) and this method would be dynamically generated for you.

Comment: Actually I am confused, which one to choose best answer. Both wjandrea's and dessert's answer are correct. So I am thinking which one to choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A oneliner using `awk` (i.e. GNU Awk):

```awk
awk 'BEGIN{printf"public String toString() {\n    return \"{ \""}{gsub(";$","");printf" + \"";if(NR>1){printf","};printf$3"=\" + "$3}END{print" + \"}\";\n}"}'
```

Use it like this:

```awk
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf"public String toString() {\n    return \"{ \""}{gsub(";$","");printf" + \"";if(NR>1){printf","};printf$3"=\" + "$3}END{print" + \"}\";\n}"}' <<EOF
> private int port;
> private String portName;
> private ArrayList portList;
> private int id;
> EOF
public String toString() {
    return "{ " + "port=" + port + ",portName=" + portName + ",portList=" + portList + ",id=" + id + "}";
}
```

#### Script version with explaining commentary

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# do the following before processing the text
BEGIN {
  # print this text, '\n' is a line break and '\"' a literal '"'
  printf "public String toString() {\n    return \"{ \""
}
{
  # remove semicolon at the end of the line
  gsub(";$","");
  # print ' + "'
  printf " + \"";
  # if the line number is > 1 print ','
  if (NR > 1) { printf "," };
  # print the third row followed by '=" + ' and the third row again
  printf $3"=\" + "$3
}
# do the following after processing the text
END {
  # print ' + "}";\n}', '\n' is a line break
  print " + \"}\";\n}"
}
```

Save it as e.g. `generate_toString`, make it executable with `chmod +x generate_toString` and use it like this:

```awk
$ ./generate_toString <<EOF
> private int port;
> private String portName;
> private ArrayList portList;
> private int id;
> EOF
public String toString() {
    return "{ " + "port=" + port + ",portName=" + portName + ",portList=" + portList + ",id=" + id + "}";
}
```

While this does what you asked for, to solve your actual problem there are *far* better approaches, see [@DavidFoerster](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980212/how-can-i-generate-tostring-method-from-fields/980285#comment1575103_980212)'s as well as [@nickb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980212/how-can-i-generate-tostring-method-from-fields/980285#comment1575139_980212)'s comment above. There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Your solution works perfectly. I especially liked the oneliner.  And yes, it was actually my mistake that I forgot the '+' before last bracket. So, what you have done is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Create Java toString() method from stdin.

while read line; do
    word_last="${line##* }"
    name="${word_last%;}"
    if [[ $pairs ]]; then
        printf -v pair '",%s=" + %s + ' "$name" "$name"
    else
        printf -v pair '"%s=" + %s + ' "$name" "$name"
    fi
    pairs+="$pair"
done

printf '%s\n' 'public String toString() {'
printf '    return "{ " + %s"}";\n' "$pairs"
printf '%s\n' '}'
```

Call like this:

```
$ bash create_java_toString.sh << EOF
> private int port;
> private String portName;
> private ArrayList portList;
> private int id;
> EOF
public String toString() {
    return "{ " + "port=" + port + ",portName=" + portName + ",portList=" + portList + ",id=" + id + "}";
}
```

More examples:

```
$ bash create_java_toString.sh << EOF
> private int i;
> private int j;
> EOF
public String toString() {
    return "{ " + "i=" + i + ",j=" + j + "}";
}
$ bash create_java_toString.sh << EOF
> EOF
public String toString() {
    return "{ " + "}";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. Your solution works perfectly as expected. And yes I tried to do this my self, but couldn't go further than separating the fields, as I don't know much about commands.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you intend to use these script but this should start you in the right direction:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# get the argumetenst from the command line

# Sample terminal usage
# tostring -p port -n portName -l portLiat -i id


echo ""
echo ""

while getopts :p:n:l:i: option
do
        case "${option}" in
                p) port=${OPTARG};;
                n) portName=${OPTARG};;
                l) portList=${OPTARG};;
                i) id=${OPTARG};;
                \?) 
                        echo ""
                        echo -e "\e[0;31m Please supply the required values: $OPTARG \e[0m" 1>&2 
                        echo ""
                        echo " Usage: tostring -p port -n portName -l portList -i id"
                        echo ""
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                : )
                        echo "Invalid option $OPTARG requires an argument" 1>&2
                        ;;
        esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1))

echo ""
echo ""

echo -e "\e[0;33m public String toString() {"
echo -e "       return "{ " + "port=" + "$port" + ",portName=" + "$portName" + ",portList=" + "$portList" + ",id=" + "$id" "}";"
echo ""
echo ""
echo -e "}"
echo -e "\e[0m"
```

More info:

https://sookocheff.com/post/bash/parsing-bash-script-arguments-with-shopts/

Comment: I think you have not understood the question properly. The name of fields are not fixed. They will be different for different class.